# In Django how would you setup user permissions for a user to only have access to a rest api?

Tags: django

In our project users can generally login to the system and access vaious web-pages. There is also a rest-api - users can access certain information through rest api as well (token authentication). Now there is one user that only should have api-access - login only through an api call returning the token. Access to web-pages in not desired and should be prevented for this user.

How can we set this up? Is it possible right out of the box or is it necessary to adapt permission classes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use api keys for the rest api to make it only accessible for the user with the api key